# How can I edit my .bst file to add an extra period after the author's name?

Tags: apa-style, back-referencing

I'm using \bibliographystyle{apalike} and want my references to appear

- not as "Smith, J. (2019)" but rather "Smith, John. (2019)"
- not as "Jones, M.T. (2019)." but as Jones, Mary T. (2019)"

I already managed to make the full first name appear by editing the .blt file thanks to input from another Q on this forum, but I'm not sure how to add this extra period after the first name (unless there is a middle initial) and before the date.

I realize this a very technical question, but I dare not edit the apalikefull.blt file without expert advice.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}

\usepackage{phonrule}

\usepackage{gb4e, cgloss}
\def\Id#1{\vskip-.32cm\hskip.01cm\vtop{#1}}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
%\stepcounter{section} % So that the labels have different values
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{times}

 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
 
 \titleformat{\paragraph}
 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
 \titlespacing*{\paragraph}
 {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
 
 
 \linenumbers

This work involves a study by Smith (\citeyear{Smith2019}).

\clearpage

\bibliography{aymara1}

\bibliographystyle{apalikefull.bst}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you consider  using `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: I already adjust the apacite.blt file to work, so I hesitate to adopt something new where I need to make more edits, but I'm really a novice here so yes I'd consider anything.

Comment: Could you post  a minimal (complete) code? Biblatex is easier to customise, as it uses a LaTeX syntax.

Comment: Sure thing, I produce a complete code (excuses, it is not minimal, I don't want to leave anything out for fear of producing some trouble)

Comment: Unrelated, but it's best to load `gb4e` relatively late in the loading order, and `hyperref` should be loaded last (unless used with certain other packages that require it to be loaded before them). You don't need to load `cgloss4e` which is loaded by `gb4e` and then overwritten by `cgloss`. The `times` package is better replaced with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.  I've removed the `apacite` tag, since you're not using that package.

Comment: Thanks! I am using APACITE, I just modified it and renamed it.